# using if else statement in js to check to see if an html form element is equal to a certain number

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/
I've javascript code that allows users to load more posts, and i want to use
if else statement to check to see if an html form element is equal to a certain number then the click function would transfer the user to another html page..
here is the html code

```
<ul id="myList">

<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
<li>Seven</li>
<li>Eight</li>
<li>Nine</li>
<li>Ten</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

and the js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
```

as you can notice

```
if(x == size_li){
                $('#loadMore').hide();
```

i want it to transfer the user instead of hide it

Comment: What form element? What number? Code shown doesn't match written description so what should be done? Is code shown currently working? This question needs clarification

Comment: please check this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/ all i wanna do is after it load the last li when i click load more it transfer me to another web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `:visible` selector as a check to see if last one is visible

```
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
  if( $('#myList li:last').is(':visible') ){
     document.location = 'new/url';
     return;
  }
  // your other code

})
```

Comment: i can't thank you enough..it worked fine